# Rails strong params, how to allow empty params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have set these strong params:

```
def my_model_params
  params.require(:my_model).permit(:field)
end
```

But sometimes the form is sent empty and I get this error:

> param is missing or the value is empty: my_model

How can I allow the form to be empty when still using strong params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fetch`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch).

> Returns a parameter for the given key. If the key can’t be found,
> there are several options: With no other arguments, it will raise an
> ActionController::ParameterMissing error; if a second argument is
> given, then that is returned (converted to an instance of
> ActionController::Parameters if possible); if a block is given, then
> that will be run and its result returned.

```
def my_model_params
  params.fetch(:my_model, {})
        .permit(:field)
end
```

The reason you want to use this over `params.permit(my_model: [ :field ])` is that it will always return an `ActionController::Parameters` instance instead of nil.